# How do I register a second android app in HERE freemium or change the name of my first app?

Tags: here-api, here-android

Last year I created a Freemium account with HERE and managed to create an access key id and secret and amazingly it all works. I have since updated the app and given it a new name and now the maps don't work, even with the second set of keys I generated.

Is it possible to have more than one app in the freemium account and if so how do I do that? Alternatively, can I change the name of the existing App in HERE?

Answer (score 1):

OK, seems like I screwed up somewhere. The maps in the updated and renamed app DO work with the original HERE keys.
After many hours of ferreting around on the HERE site and elsewhere I think I can also answer both of my own questions as "No" and "No".

Comment: It sounds like you are using the 4.x versions of the HERE SDK (Explore, Navigate or Lite): So, yes, you can change the app name. And yes, you can have more than one app running with the same credentials. The credentials for the new editions are not tied to a specific app or project nor they require a specific naming for your app(s).

Comment: Yes, I am using v4.6 of the SDK. Could you explain how to change the app name in my HERE project please? I guess it doesn't actually matter since I have found that I can use the same credentials in my new app but it would be interesting to know how to do it.

Comment: It depends on the platform. But changing the name of an app is not something that depends on the HERE SDK. A good general approach may be to grep the app name and change it via any text editor.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I know how to change my app name in Android Studio - my problem is how to change it on the HERE SDK site.

Comment: I am not aware that the app name needs to be set on the HERE site. You can set a project name or something like this, but it is no related to your actual app name you use in your app. Therefore, there should not be a need to change the "internal" name on the site, if I am not wrong.

Comment: I think you're correct that the app name isn't required (it's some time ago that I first did this - memory like a sieve!). However, HERE Freemium seems to only allow one project, for which you can have 2 sets of credentials, so if you want more than 2 apps with different credentials you can't. However, my immediate problem is solved in that I can use the same credentials in multiple apps - bearing in mind that these apps are purely for personal use, never to be released into the big wide world.

Comment: Yes, and you can have more than 2 apps published with same creds, although it seems you get only two different set of creds. But that should be more than enough, according to documentation, https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.7.3.0/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html#set-your-here-credentials, it is possible to use the same creds for multiple apps. HERE bills against the transactions per credentials, not per app. That means you should be careful with security and not leak your credentials, of course.

Answer (score 1):

**Note - I had used HERE Explorer addition and tested with first 2 sample examples from - https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/explore/android**

We can run two apps with same/different credentials, please follow below steps -

1. You need to generate and download 2 credentials.properties file from the developer portal. Please see the attached screenshot -
   [image]
2. After downloading above files you can put those credentials in your app's **"Android.Manifest"** file, so for 2 apps there will be two **"credentials.properties"** file, put the credentials in tags -

3. For every app, your **package="com.package.name"** should be unique from each other.
4. Please see screenshot of 2 app's running in my phone -

[image]

Comment: That's a good point, the package name should be unique, otherwise Android OS does not allow to install different apps at the same time. This is something more general, not specific for the HERE SDK, as for the HERE SDK itself: It is almost agnostic of the package name that is actually being used. Please correct me, if I am wrong.